# Package gradle dependencies for offline build

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I have a Java project which I need to transfer to a network that isn't connected to the internet.  Is there a way to download and package all of its dependencies ahead of time so that I can build my project (with gradle) without any internet access?

I've tried grabbing everything in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` and pushing it to the network's Artifactory instance but some of the dependencies, like com.android.application, only have a POM file but no JAR file.

Comment: Could you just manually upload all required dependencies to the isolated artifactory?  You could get a list of them via `./gradlew dependencies`.

Comment: How do I manually download them?

Comment: When I have to, I usually go to an existing artifactory and find the package/version I want.  Then, usually there's a link to browse the files (including POMs, etc), and then upload them to your own.  Every artifactory is a little different, but it usually works w/ a little trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a private maven repository on your offline LAN.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Daniel Walker Please see https://help.sonatype.com/en/sonatype-nexus-repository.html.